# What does it mean when get [screen is terminating] after typing in screen ls?

Tags: unix, gnu-screen

I a script running in the 1 screen session. I check how many screens I have. I mistype:

```
[name@server] $ screen ls  #I forgot a - in -ls
[screen is terminating]
```

What does it mean when screen is terminating? It seems to keep running. I'm debating on whether or not I should scrap this current task in case something went wrong